# Javascript syntax error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

i recieve this error when i launching my javascript below:

```
if(isPartOfIndex(new Array[25,20], indexClaimTypeRow)    ){
        //display size

         listItem = '<li id="soze" data-theme="c"><h3>Size:</h3>' +
        '<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c">' +
          '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="recieptVat">' +
           '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="1.0" />' +
            '<label for="radio-choice-1">1.0</label>' +
            '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="1.4"  />' +
            '<label for="radio-choice-2">1.4</label>' +
            '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="2.0"  />' +
            '<label for="radio-choice-3">2.0</label>' +
          '</fieldset>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</li>';

      $('#itemFieldslist').append(listItem);

      $('#itemFieldslist').listview('refresh');
    }
```

The error message displayed is:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
>   Array[25,20]')

here is the isPartOfindex which expects an array as the first parameter

```
function isPartOfIndex(indexRow, indexType){

    for(var i = 0; i < indexRow.length; i++){
        if(indexRow[i] == indexType){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `new Array[25,20]` is the same as `new Array[20]`, i.e. you are trying to access the property `20` of the `Array` function (which does not exist) and call it as a constructor function (`new`).

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the *Peer Pressure* badge or what? Such a silly error that even seems to be intended.

Comment: Na it was a stupid syntax mistake. i am very new to javascript and i keep coding it like JAVA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be `new Array(25, 20)` or just `[25, 20]`

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your code to:

```
   if(isPartOfIndex(new Array(25,20), indexClaimTypeRow)    ){
    //display size

     listItem = '<li id="soze" data-theme="c"><h3>Size:</h3>' +
    '<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c">' +
      '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="recieptVat">' +
       '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="1.0" />' +
        '<label for="radio-choice-1">1.0</label>' +
        '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="1.4"  />' +
        '<label for="radio-choice-2">1.4</label>' +
        '<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="2.0"  />' +
        '<label for="radio-choice-3">2.0</label>' +
      '</fieldset>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</li>';

  $('#itemFieldslist').append(listItem);

  $('#itemFieldslist').listview('refresh');
}
```

new Array[25,20] is not proper declaration for your array.

Answer (score 1):

Just need `[20, 25]` instead of `new Array[20, 25]`. You also can use `new Array(20, 25)`